# Laravel Pass Authenticated to Every View

Tags: laravel

I need to pass a collection to every view; the collection contains the IDs of the items in the user's shopping cart. I've tried Service Providers and a BaseClass but neither worked as (apparently) `Auth` hasn't been registered at those points and only returns `null`.

What's the best way get records from an **authenticated** user and pass it to every view?

#### Edit: here's the relevant code

#### User.php

```
public static function getCart()
{
    if (Auth::guest()) {
        return [];
    }

    $collection = new \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection();
    $collection = Auth::user()->cart()->pluck('post_id');

    return $collection;
}
```

#### CartServiceProvider.php

```
namespace App\Providers;

use View;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class CartServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
        View::share('cart', User::getCart());
    }

    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

In any view...

```
<?php dd($cart); ?>
```

returns `[]` because `Auth` hasn't been registered yet, so the empty array is returned.

Comment: Are you returning an instance of the Auth'ed user in your service provider?

Comment: what about view composers ?

Comment: I was about to ask if he had tried that within a service provider.

Comment: @jaysingkar Yes, I created a view composer in a service provider, but `Auth` isn't available there. Is there a better place to do this?

Comment: @Jamesmcconnon I'm trying to, but `Auth::user()` returns `null` in the service provider.

Comment: Could you post your service provider code?

Comment: @Jamesmcconnon Sure thing. See edited...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer [on Laracasts](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/l5-service-provider-for-sharing-view-variables) and it seems to work quite well.

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/l5-service-provider-for-sharing-view-variables

From the OP @imJohnBon: "I managed to solve this issue by creating 2 files. First a ComposerServiceProvider which uses a wildcard to be applied to every view and not just particular views:"

```
namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Contracts\View\Factory as ViewFactory;

class ComposerServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

    public function boot(ViewFactory $view)
    {
        $view->composer('*', 'App\Http\ViewComposers\GlobalComposer');
    }

    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

"And then the corresponding GlobalComposer where I share variables that should be available in all views:"

```
namespace App\Http\ViewComposers;

use Illuminate\Contracts\View\View;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class GlobalComposer {

    public function compose(View $view)
    {
        $view->with('currentUser', Auth::user());
    }

}
```

Comment: I was going to suggest something similar :)

Comment: Oh and godbless Laracasts as usual, best 9.99 i spend a month. (Not a paid endorsement)

Comment: Agreed. I searched for hours today and never found that result until someone on Laracasts pointed it out to me.